# How can I make a B spline with specific values of 1st derivative at breakpoints (not only ends) using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, splines, bspline, cubic-spline

I used `csape` function in curve fitting toolbox, it enables the user of choosing derivative values at the both ends.

Is there a way to control the value of the derivative a specific breakpoint?

I want to set one of the values of the derivatives to be zero at one breakpoint, to make it a maximum.

Here is the code:

```
%% Times
k=0;
Tc = 1; %step time in second
Td = .15*Tc; %the DSP time
t0=k*Tc;
t1=t0+Td;
t2=t0+Tc;
t3=t2+Td;
Tm=.5*Tc; 
tmaxh=t0+Tm;

%% Z Height
hgs=0;
hge=0;
Hao=.12;
Lan=.079;
Laf=.2;
Lab=.05;
Ds=.6;
Lao=.6667*Ds; 
qb=10;
qf=10;

%% Spline generation using cublic spline.
tt=[t0 t1 tmaxh t2 t3];
zz=[hgs+Lan hgs+Laf*sind(qb)+Lan*cosd(qb) Hao hge+Lab*sind(qf)+Lan*cosd(qf) hge+Lan];
cs = csape(tt,zz,[1 0 0 0 1],[0 0 0 0 0])
figure
fnplt(cs)
```

After the comment `%% Spline generation using cubic spline.`
I have two vectors one for time and one for another value that changes with time and I want to make b-spline of 3rd order.

I used `csape` because it enables the user to determine the value of the derivatives at end points.`cs = csape(tt,zz,[1 0 0 0 1],[0 0 0 0 0])` the ones are to tell the tool to make the 1st derivative at the end points = 0.

**I want the point that occurs at time = tmaxh to be the maximum point on the spline.**

I tried making this by placing 1 in the `[1 0 0 0 1]` so it become `[1 0 1 0 1]` as I know that the 1st derivative at a maximum is 0, but this method didn't work for me.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe [this](http://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24443-slm-shape-language-modeling) can be of some help

Comment: setting the derivative to zero won't guarantee a maximum/minimum...you could have a saddle point instead.  Can you provide some of your code, and show exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: @gariepy, I have added the code and more clarification about my goal.